# Problems installing the R package amap in a Mac 10.9.5

Tags: r, macos, csh, install.packages

I am trying to install the package amap in R to do some parallel distance matrix calculations.

I run:

```
 install.packages("amap", dependencies = TRUE)
```

and I get this error:

```
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [pop.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘amap’
* removing ‘/Users/javier/Library/R/3.1/library/amap’
```

However, gfortran-4.8 is installed in my computer:

```
gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gfortran/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gfortran --with-gmp=/Users/fx/devel/gcc/deps-static/x86_64 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

I read somewhere here that a way around is typing the following in the .bash_source

```
alias fixrs="launchctl setenv PATH /usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
```

And then execute `fixrs` in the terminal. I use .tcshrc so I typed

```
alias fixrs launchctl setenv PATH /usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

on my .tcshrc, and execute the `fixrs` command in the terminal before launching RStudio or the R Console and I keep getting the same error (also mentioning that I have also tried change to bash, generate a .bash_profile include the command and the lunch RStudio and the result was the same).

should the comment be placed in a specific part of the .tcshrc file? is my bash to tcshrc translation wrong? I have also tried `alias fixrs "launchctl setenv PATH /usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"`

Anyway, at this stage I don't really know how to proceed to simply install amap. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check out the r-sig-mac mailing list archives for lots of useful advice concerning which compilers, command path modifications, etc.  to use.

Comment: Javier, any solution yet?  I have the same problem, except on my system it not only seems hardwired for 4.8.2 but also for a different darwin kernal.  If you figured it out, you could put it as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: hi Bryan...I solved it but I can't remember exactly how (I did not note it down :(, sorry). I believe what I did was simply downloading the binary file (amap_0.8-12.tgz) and install it from source. Then I remember I still had some problems with some libraries (*.h). To solve that I installed the required packages with macports and symlink the libraries to the R required directory using `ln -s`. I hope this helps. Ah!, and I installed it using the latest version of RStudio...